# Options for DLNA output of audio?

Tags: macos, streaming

Are there any apps which can stream my audio output (either all of it, or from a specific source/program) via DLNA so my DLNA-enabled products (TV & DVD surround-sound system) can pick it up and use it?

I've looked at Airfoil (not DLNA) and Serviio (wouldn't start on my Lion macbook air), and all the other "usual" servers just serve files on the machine - mainly I want to stream my audio for those times I'm watching youtube videos (talks/presentations mainly) and internet radio.