# MacOS sound output to DLNA renderer - what are the options?

Tags: audio, mediaplayer

I saw this question (with no answers) from a few years ago:  [Options for DLNA output of audio?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54622/options-for-dlna-output-of-audio)

It's now 2021 and I find it hard to believe that things haven't moved on.

I want to be able to stream either the system sound output or the output from any media player that could access the local media library to a DLNA uPnP audio renderer device (Pure Jongo A2) but can't find a mac application that's capable of any type of playback.

There are plenty of DLNA server applications available, which are little use as the A2 doesn't have a physical interface, it just plays what it's told.

On android, applications exist to play local media and select the output as the A2 so I know it's possible. These include BubbleuPnP and AirMusic, which happily operate as local media players outputting to the jongo.

I have tried AirFoil, but it doesn't see the A2 on the network and seems more focused to the Apple AirPlay system.

Serviio is only suitable for clients accessing the mac as a media server rather than telling the renderer (A2) what to play, and there are other server softwares that fall into the same category.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My system is running Catalina.

Thakyou

Answer (score 1):

The things don't move on.

Same problem for me. There are tons of media servers, but no really convincing audio renderers with upnp/dlna on the Mac. I tried really many programs.

Solutions which are working with some disadvantages:

- [OpenHome Player](http://openhome.org/pages/use/downloads/mac): Seems to be the best option, but no gapless playing and the application crashes after one hour or so.
- Kodi (used as a dlna receiver only): Works quite well, but "a bit heavy", also no gapless playing and after some time the possibility to change the volume of the music gets lost (change the volume on the amplifier then or restart Kodi)
- Virtual Linux machine with gmrender-resurrect: Functionally gmrender-resurrect is better than any audio renderer on the Mac (gapless playing works, changing the volume works), but the VM needs many resources, and the audio quality is less than with Kodi and OpenHome Player directly on the Mac, which is audible on a good stereo. The problem is not the VM but Linux. Also if you boot the Mac directly with Linux then the audio quality is a bit degraded. Apple pays more attention for these details.

Solutions which are **not** working:

- JRiver Media Center: This is recognized as a dlna receiver, but it plays the songs in a completely wrong order. Not usable.
- FooBar2000: There is a Mac version, but the necessary upnp plugin only works on windows.

I use BubbleUpnp with Kodi on Mac as the audio renderer and Linn Kazoo or BubbleUpnp on Android as the remote control.